How can I reference a bib-file on Mac for a qmd-file
I want to use a bib-file in a qmd-file in the YAML section. I tried this with Mac OS:
bibliography: 
  - '`r system("/Users/.../my_bib_file.bib")`'

But I receive the following error:
/Users/.../my_bib_file.bib: line 1: @online{@jez2021,: command not found
/Users/.../my_bib_file.bib: line 2: title: command not found
/Users/.../my_bib_file.bib: line 3: author: command not found
date: illegal time format
usage: date [-jnRu] [-I[date|hours|minutes|seconds]] [-f input_fmt]
            [-r filename|seconds] [-v[+|-]val[y|m|w|d|H|M|S]]
            [[[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.SS] | new_date] [+output_fmt]
File  not found in resource path

Do I have an error in the bibliography expression? Thanks for any help.

In order to link to the bibtex file from quarto you provide the path to the file, like so:
---
bibliography: references.bib
---

If the file is not in the same folder as the qmd file you provide a absolute (~/ means your users home directory)
---
bibliography: ~/path/to/pathreferences.bib
---

or relative path.
---
bibliography: path/to/references.bib
---

See the quarto documentation on citations for details
